# This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I am unable to run a basic template project because I get the error:

```
This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
```

I can see the emulator, but it is doing a full OS boot every single time I try and run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator system requirements are documented here.

[Setup and System Requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Does your system comply?

Comment: I am running it inside of an emulator. I am assuming that might be "Hyper-V" which means I can't run it?

Comment: The emulator doesn't support running in a VM.